# Shell CurrentItem makes tab bar disappear

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have a shell, that when I add [`CurrentItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs#tab-selection), the `TabBar` disappears. When I remove `CurrentItem` the `TabBar` shows.

Why is the `TabBar` getting hidden when adding this attribute?

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Colorize.Views" 
       xmlns:colorize="clr-namespace:Colorize" 
       x:DataType="colorize:AppShell"
       Title="Colorize"
       x:Class="Colorize.AppShell"
       CurrentItem="{x:Reference scanner}">

  <Shell.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <!-- Styles -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Shell.Resources>

  <TabBar>
    <ShellContent Title="About" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AboutPage}" />
    <ShellContent x:Name="scanner" Title="Scanner" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ScannerPage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Browse" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ItemsPage}" />
  </TabBar>
</shell>
```

Comment: It seems a bug, you can open an issue at https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: Hmm, okay. A workaround is to add `CurrentItem = scanner;` in the constructor of `AppShell`.